# bash: ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py : no such file or directory

Tags: linux

I'm trying to configure interfaces and get status. I get the following error:

```
$./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --status
bash: ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py : no such file or directory
```

I do not know why this file does not exist. Did I make a mistake in the dpdk installation? My ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS and I'm working with VirtualBox.

```
~/ofp/scripts/dpdk$ ls ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py  
 ls: cannot access './tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py': No such file or directory
 $head ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py 
 head: cannot open './tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py' for reading: No such file or 
 directory
 $python ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --status
 python: cant open file './tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py': [Errno 2] No such file or   directory
```

Comment: Post output of `ls ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py` and `head ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py`. It might be due a bad interpreter.

Comment: You can also try `python ./tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py --status`.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775429/bash-tools-dpdk-nic-bind-py-no-such-file-or-directory